# How to create a sitemap.json file?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, automation, sitemap

I need to create a sitemap.json file from a list of URLs, which means I cannot do it automatically from the server.

The output file sitemap.json would look like this:

```
{
  "domain": "http://www.google.com",
  "lastmod": { "year": "2013", "month": "01", "day": "24" },
  "filetype": "html",

  "pages": [
    {
      "page": "home",
      "update-frequency": "monthly",
      "lastmod": { "year": "2013", "month": "01", "day": "24" },
      "priority": "1"
    },
```

I'm able to do that easily for an XML sitemap, but I am a bit puzzled on how to do so in JSON. Any clue? Thanks.

Comment: Absent your source file, I suppose you could generate the XML sitemap and convert it (via tool or lib) to JSON.

Comment: @orde I tried that, but that seems the data inside an XML sitemap is very different from the one. Looks more like that: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>

      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>

      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>

      <priority>0.8</priority>

   </url>

</urlset> `

Comment: I was kinda wondering this too. It looks like NPM has a Grunt task for creating a JSON sitemap. Have you tried this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-json-sitemap